# Is $\sum\limits_{k=2}^{\infty}{\sin(k!)}/{(k\log(k))}$ convergent or divergent? How can I prove it?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, trigonometric-series

How can I prove that $~\displaystyle\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(k!)}{k\log(k)}~$ converges ? Both [Leibniz's criterion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test) and [Dirichlet's test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet's_test) seem

rather inadequate for handling this particular task.

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange! We do not make a habit of fully answering questions which do not show good faith on part of the poster. You have only posted a question without any effort shown on your half. We are not a question and answer site. However we do not mind offering help with problems or even giving most of a solution if the OP has shown effort on their part.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I didn't mean to it. I tried to think about the alternating series test, since $\sin(k!)$ will result in values on the interval (-1, 1), but this doesn't seems to be valid...
After that I tried to compare it with
$1/k\log(k)$, since  $\sin(k!) \leqslant |1|$
but I don't know how to prove if this last one converges or diverges

Comment: @MaycownDouglas: $~\displaystyle\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac1{k\log(k)}~$ diverges.

Comment: You can't. It is hinged on some intimate details of irrationality of $\pi$, and probably not known at all. That is, unless the argument of sine is measured in degrees ;-))

Comment: Ever got an answer from your institution (if this is homework) ?